# How can I use an online style.css on the visual studio code markdown preview?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

I found a markdown css in the github and I want to use it to preview my vscode's md file.
the css file url is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/gh-pages/github-markdown.css

#### vscode settings.json:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, Microsoft YaHei", 
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "markdown.styles": [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/gh-pages/github-markdown.css"
    ]
}
```

But nothing happened.
What should I do?

Comment: I added a way to get sindresorhus' package to work with a little node hacking if you don't us node I can provide a lengthier description -- also, I've found this URL to be a bit nicer to work with using GitHub content -- https://rawgit.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/gh-pages/github-markdown.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use a local .css file such as `d:\vscode-markdown.css`, then your configuration should be

```
"markdown.styles": [
    "file:///D:/vscode-markdown.css"
]
```

Comment: This will not work in modern versions of VS Code. Local styles files can only be loaded from inside the workspace

Answer (score 1):

The css file of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/gh-pages/github-markdown.css is not suit for the editor.

the document [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown) have written the format of a preview css.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

---

- Workplace setting: put the `style.css` to the `Workspace folder` and configuration `"markdown.styles": ["style.css"]` will also work.
- Global setting: use the absolute local path with `files:///` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that vscode [normalizes paths](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/parts/markdown/browser/markdownExtension.ts#L158), starting from the location of the markdown file itself, so it seems a universal absolute path specification is only feasible from the root of the file system, rather than the root of the project.

#### Update

I just noticed that vscode is sending Application Insights to the team at MS, based on the failure to resolve the files. What is shown below works, but if it's raising false errors than it may be a bit drastic. You should at least disable insights if you need to do something like this, or simply copy the css into the same folder as the markdown instead.

I now just keep the `markdown.css` in the root folder, and saturate the config with paths allowing markdown to be placed into various sub-folders within a project. Only one actual source of styles is needed here of course, just giving vscode more places to find it.

#### project folders

```
root
├─ .vscode 
│  └─ settings.json                 
│
├─ config
│  └─ README.md
│
├─ src
│  └─ client
│     └─ README.md
│
├─ markdown.css
└─ README.md
```

#### settings.json

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
  "markdown.styles": [
    "./markdown.css",
    "../markdown.css",
    "../../markdown.css",
    "../../../markdown.css"
  ]
}
```

#### markdown.css

```
body {
  font-family: cordova, Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;        
  color: #333;
}

body, body * {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black;
}

pre {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: -1.25em !important;
}

pre div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: auto;
}

pre code * {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: #eee !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are out of date. For using github styling in the preview, try [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles)

---

For loading any stylesheet into the preview, https links would normally work in `markdown.styles` but github [returns `X-Frame-Options: deny`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8287#issuecomment-230021773) on that resource so we cannot embed in the markdown preview

As a workaround, you can:

- Use an https mirror for the github content
- Download the stylesheet to your workspace and use [`markdown.styles`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_using-your-own-css) to include it.

  ```
  "markdown.styles": ["github-markdown.css"]
  ```

  **Important**: The markdown preview can only load stylesheets from inside the current workspace.

Comment: I had to realise that this works, despite there always are errors raised, telling about that the css could not be loaded!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little set up I have for a personal project -- It's pretty close to what you were initially looking for.

~/.vscode/settings.json

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
  },
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true
  },
  "markdown.styles": [
    "tools/editors/vscode/settings/markdown.styles.css"
  ]
}
```

~/package.json

```
{
  "name": "seed",
  "main": "index.js",

  ...

  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node tools/editors/vscode/settings/markdown.styles.js",
  },

  ...

  "devDependencies": {
    "generate-github-markdown-css": "^1.2.0",
  }
}
```

~/tools/editors/vscode/settings/markdown.styles.js

```
'use strict'

 const fs = require('fs')
 const githubMarkdownCss = require('generate-github-markdown-css')

 /**
  * Use the stylesheet from github's markdown over the vscode defaults.
  */
 githubMarkdownCss((err, css) => {
   css = `body {\n  background-color: #fff;\n}\n\n${css.replace(/.markdown-body/g, 'body')}`
   fs.writeFileSync('tools/editors/vscode/settings/markdown.styles.css', css, 'utf8')
 })

 //NOTE: the CSS var is set with es6 string interpolation. (node 4.x and up)
 //      the background-color is set here because GitHub inherit's it from another stylesheet -- so we need to set it.
```

Hopefully, this is helpful to someone. (also, sorry for the crazy file path)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the raw URL from your Github/Gist and use it with https://rawgit.com/.

Here is an example from my VSCode settings which works. You should see Fira Sans and Fira Mono typefaces against a white background and dark text.

```
// settings.json from VSCode
{
  ...
  "markdown.styles": ["https://rawgit.com/thewazir/50486310d50fb2d6da2c8ab91d26756a/raw/1760755deb7bff05fadcaf6927c4950d256e6838/visualStudioCodeMarkdownStyles.css"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that file "https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style/blob/master/preview/github.css", we know that "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style/master/preview/github.css", the URL is not working.

I have a good idea, we can use Github Pages.

Add a submodule in your repository, like this "`git submodule add https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style.git`". And now we can use the URL "https://sepcode.github.io/vscode-markdown-style/preview/github.css" set markdown.styles.

Step:

1. clone your GitHub pages "`git clone https://github.com/SepCode/SepCode.github.io.git`"
2. `cd SepCode.github.io`
3. `git submodule add https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style.git`
4. `git commit -am 'added vscode-markdown-style module'`
5. `git push`
6. setting vscode setting.json
   `{
   "markdown.styles":["https://sepcode.github.io/vscode-markdown-style/preview/github.css"]
   }`

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76384#issuecomment-507101841